Using typescript how to get current date "local" date in "yyyy-mm-dd" format
I am using this:
const today = new Date(
    new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] + "Z"
);
console.log(today);

but returns correct date but format is  "Sun May 26 2024 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"
how can I get it in "2024-05-26" format?

that question is specific to JavaScript. that is not working for me in typescript

It's exactly this answer and  it works fine I don't think you've put enough effort into investigating this before declaring that the question marked as a dupe doesn't work for you
